# Select some columns based on WHERE in a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, blaze

So, I am working with Blaze and wanted to perform this query on a dataframe:

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM table WHERE col1 > 0
```

For `SELECT *`, this works: `d[d.col1 > 0]`. But I want `col1` and `col2` only rather than all columns. How should I go about it?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here I create `d` as: `d = Data('postgresql://uri')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also works: `d[d.col1 > 0][['col1','col2']]`

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use first subset and then boolean indexing:

```
 print (d)
   col1  col2  col3
0    -1     4     7
1     2     5     8
2     3     6     9

d = d[['col1','col2']]
print (d)
   col1  col2
0    -1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6

print (d[d.col1 > 0])
   col1  col2
1     2     5
2     3     6
```

This is same as:

```
print (d[['col1','col2']][d.col1 > 0])
   col1  col2
1     2     5
2     3     6
```

Comment: Getting this error: ```AttributeError: '_Data' object has no attribute 'loc'```.

Comment: So, it is a Blaze Data object and not a dataframe per se. Should I change the title?